# Calculating the chance of something happening over and over again

Tags: probability, statistics, economics, recursion

I'm trying to calculate the probability, and potential cost on society, of people returning to homelessness after going through the system one, two, or several more times.

Let's say that someone who enters into a homeless shelter and eventually finds suitable housing ends up costing the homeless assistance system $\$2000$ to provide all the services that helped them to resolve their housing crisis. There is a 35% chance that this person will, for any of a whole slew of reasons, return to homelessness after 2 years. In other words, after $\$2000$ was spent on them to find them a place to live, there's a 35% chance that within two years they'll end up homeless again and have to enter into a shelter, go through the whole process, and generate another $\$2000$ of costs to find them a place to live.

My question is, since this situation is recursive, in that a person could potentially become homeless over and over again throughout their lifetime, how do I calculate the "average scenario", or the cost that any given homeless person will generate on the system, over their lifetime, given the information above?

The tricky part for me is figuring out what to do with the 35%, since it's the chance that they'll return to homelessness after 2 years, not over their entire lifetime.

Any ideas?

Comment: For clarification, is it that they have a $35\%$ chance of becoming homeless every two years, or is it that after they go two years without becoming homeless again, they break the pattern and now have a $0\%$ chance? How long a lifetime is also alters the results.

Comment: Really, it's that 35% of people who exit from the homeless shelter are back in the shelter (and therefore homeless) at some point within the next two years. That's why I say that there's a 35% chance that they'll be homeless again within two years. 

I don't think that means that that 35% chance applies every two years. What happens to people if they go the two years without becoming homeless is not tracked and unknown. As for a lifetime, let's use the average US adult male life expectancy of 76 years, and say that the average homeless person is 35 years old.

Comment: You're going to have to make a bold assumption about what happens after two years, because the answer depends hugely on it. ;)

Comment: I understand this. But after two years, what happens to their chances? Also, how long is a lifetime? Or more specifically, for how many years of life is a person covered by this program? As well, let's say a person becomes homeless again a month after the program. They do so repeatedly. Does this mean they enter the program every month, with a cost of $\$24000$ per year? Does the point within the two years that they become homeless again matter?

Comment: I don't know what happens to them after two years. I assume the chances of them becoming homeless again increase with time, since expanding the range of time we're examining opens up more opportunities for something bad to happen in that person's life. Probably part of the reason why we don't track what happens after two years. 

If it helps, let's assume that it takes about a year to go through the program, so the $2000 cost is over a year of being in the program, and it wouldn't be possible for someone to enter the program every month.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so for the first iteration you have:

Note: where X is the number of homeless.

$X*2000$

This is before any one has a change to be homeless again.

If you include the second iteration you have:

$X*2000 + X*2000*0.35$

If you include the third iteration you have:

$X*2000 + X*2000*0.35 + X*2000*0.35*0.35$

Written as a summation:

$\sum_{i=0}^n X*2000*0.35^i$

Where n is the number of times you want to iterate the process. It is important to note that this is ignoring any background rise or drop in the homeless

If you calculate it as n goes to $\infty$ you would get your answer (currently I cannot remember how to do this). But for n=10 you get $3076.84.

Please note I'm not being very exact as the 35% is for within 2 years so n=10 does not mean the average cost of the person over 20 years as they could become homeless in less than the 2 years.

Comment: It would be $2000\cdot\frac{1}{1-0.35}$, for $\$3,076.92$ to the nearest cent.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This application of the infinite geometric series is actually how I calculated it the first time I tried it, but I can't shake the feeling that it isn't a complete answer, exactly for the reason that you mention in your last sentence, that "the 35% is for within 2 years so n=10 does not mean the average cost of the person over 20 years as they could become homeless in less than the 2 years."

What information would I need to be able to calculate the average cost of the person over a set amount of time?

Comment: There you as RandomUser added $\sum_{i=0}^\infty 2000*-.35^i = 2000 * 1/(1-0.35) = 3076.92$

Comment: I think you need info on the distribution of their chance to be homeless again within that 2 year period.

Comment: I think I could get that, I just have to look into the data again before I can get an actual probability distribution. How long do these questions stay up before they're forgotten? This is my first time using stackexchange and after I get off work I probably won't be able to update this for a couple days.

Comment: @Samaritan Without a lot of activity, the question is very likely to be lost in the flow. But if you comment on updates with an @[username] like I did there, then that person will be notified that you mentioned them.

Comment: @RandomUser Cool, thanks. I'm gonna think it over some more and update the question with more specifics when I have them. Thanks for your help!